# PHP Curl wrong headers?

Tags: php, curl

I'm sending content from a PHP Curl script to an API.
I'm using this is to do a POST do my script while passing json headers

```
 $query = new stdClass; 
 $query->test = 'test';
 $query = json_encode($query);
 $ch = curl_init();         
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json', 'Content-Length: '.strlen($query)]);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);               
 $res = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
```

But when I trace what the content type of the request in on the API side, I get

```
 var_dump($_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE']);
 //application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Shouldn't I get this instead?

```
 application/json
```

Comment: I think, you are `SENDING` a `REQUEST` using curl. but I dont I see any `RESPONSE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` instead of `CURLOPT_HEADER`

`CURLOPT_HEADER` can be true/false and define whether include header to response or not

FYI:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);`
These lines are redundant as you are not using https